# What is the generating function of $z^3 + 2z^5 + 5z^7 + 14 z^9+\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

What is the generating function of $z^3 + 2z^5 + 5z^7 + 14 z^9+\dots$ ?

The generating function can be written as follows:
$$A(z)=\sum_{i>2}^{\infty} a_i z^{2i+1},\text{where } a_i \text{ is the Catalan numbers} $$

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Catalan numbers go,
$$1,1,2,5,14,42,132,429, \dots$$
The generating series you are after is,
$$z^3+2z^5+5z^7+14z^9+42z^{11}+\dots$$
As Lord Shark the Unknown points out the generating function for the Catalan numbers is well known,
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}=1+z^1+2z^2+5z^3+14z^4+42z^5+...$$
To insert a single interlacing zero between the terms you need to replace $z$ with $z^2$,
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4(z^2)}}{2(z^2)}=1+(z^2)^1+2(z^2)^2+5(z^2)^3+14(z^2)^4+42(z^2)^5+\dots$$
Now multiply both sides by z,
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2}}{2z}=z+z^3+2z^5+5z^7+14z^9+42z^{11}+\dots$$

To remove the unwanted initial z, simply subtract it from both sides and so the generating function you are after is,
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2}}{2z}-z=z^3+2z^5+5z^7+14z^9+42z^{11}+...$$
There is a marvellous online tool you can use to quickly check what generating series a generating function expands into. It's the Taylor Series Expansion Calculator at https://www.numberempire.com/taylorseriesexpansion.php

Comment: Thanks. When we replace $z$ with $z^2$, we will get $1(z^2)^0 + 1(z^2)^1+2(z^2)^2+5(z^2)^3 ... $, right?

Comment: That's right! And then multiply by $z$. I've put the extra steps into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now.

Comment: by the way, there is a minor typo, $z^2$ was supposed to be $4z^2$ in the two euqations you added earlier. (I couldn't edit it, it says at least 6 characters...)
Thanks for your solution again.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nz^n$ be the generating function for the Catalan numbers. Then your series is the generating function of the odd terms minus the first term i.e. given by
$$
\frac{C(z)-C(-z)}{2}-z
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As I tested, this will generate ${x,0,4x^3,0...}$, not exactly same with the question...

Comment: Multiply the generating function associated with $x, 0, 4x^3,0,\dots$ by $x$ then replace all occurrences of $x$ with $\sqrt{x}$ and simplify

Comment: @MartinHansen I don't understand, can you provide more details? thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I was talking rubbish. I've had a proper look at this now and have just posted a most excellent answer - Hope you like it ! Green tick it if so. If you need to prove how to get the generating function for the Catalan Numbers just ask. It's a quotable well known result. I enjoyed puzzling over the question.